# What is meant by "projected normal to the face"?

Tags: geometry

I am looking at lattice structure:

[image]

The part that got me wondering:

[image]

I am trying to calculate according to some equations online, and came across this section where they mention "projected normal to the face". I get what projected area is - take a 3-D area and "convert" it to a 2D area, but what does it mean to project "normal to the face"? - I can't make sense of it.

Comment: Here "normal to" means "at right angles to" (this is a well-known mathematical term). So if the face was horizontal, this would be the vertical projection.

Comment: I guess this means that you imagine an observer looking at your object, and you project your 3d object on the plane "on which the face of the observer lives"

Comment: Is there any picture illustrating this? I still have trouble seeing it. I imagine we are looking at a 3D shape, but the we project it to a 2D area and flip the area 90 degrees. But it doesnt make much sense to me why we would do that.